# How can I elm-make .elm files into HTML templates, rather than HTML files?

Tags: html, ejs, elm

I'm just taking a look at Elm.

I can successfully write a page in Elm and can produce an HTML file with elm-make.

I'd like elm-make to produce an HTML template, to be rendered with NodeJS.  Obviously, I can change the output suffix to `.ejs`, for example.

How can I have a couple of constants in Elm replaced with template tags?  Is `sed` the way to do this, or is there a better method?

I only need a couple of constants to be inserted.  I don't need handling of other tags, or iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you can do is compile to js instead of to the default html. using this command

```
elm-make FileName.elm --output FileName.js
```

Then have node initialize Elm into an html such as

```
<div id="main"></div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script>
    var node = document.getElementById('main');
    var app = Elm.Main.embed(node);
</script>
```

for more information, see [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html)